# Código JavaScript dentro de un campo textarea

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un `textarea` y un editor en `javascript` que lee el contenido y permite editarlo. Cuando el contenido es por ejemplo:

```
<script>
    alert('hi');
</script>
```

El `script` se ejecuta a pesar de ser texto dentro de un `textarea`. No puedo borrar o quitar las etiquetas porque el editor lo necesita tal y como lo envía luego. ¿Hay alguna manera de que todo lo que hay dentro de un `textarea` sea tratado como texto normal y no como `html`, `tags`, o `scripts`?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés.

Comment: Lo que te esta pasando se conoce como [`XSS`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (Cross-site scripting). Existente muchas formas de evitarlo. Personalmente creo que deberías sanear el contenido de este `textarea` antes de guardarlo.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás cargando actualmente el texto en el textarea? ¿Cómo se genera? ¿Cual es la fuente? ¿Podrías mostrar el código?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes reemplazar los tags de HTML de `<script>` dentro del `textarea` por los códigos HTML correspondientes:

```
<textarea>
    &lsaquo;script&rsaquo;
        alert('hola');
    &lsaquo;/script&rsaquo;
</textarea>
```

De ese modo, se verá como corresponde pero no se debería ejecutar:

```
<textarea>
  &lsaquo;script&rsaquo;alert('hola');&lsaquo;/script&rsaquo;
</textarea>
```

[Acá](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp) tienes un listado de los símbolos HTML:

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

La única manera que veo posible hacer esto es

Con jquery

```js
$("#boton").click(function(){
  $('#txtarea').val("<script type='text\/javascript'>var num1 = 1;var num2 = 2;var suma = num1 + num2;alert(suma);<\/script>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Insertar">
```

Con Javascript

```js
function cargarScript(){
  document.getElementById("txtarea").innerHTML = "<script type='text\/javascript'>var num1 = 1;var num2 = 2;var suma = num1 + num2;alert(suma);<\/script>";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="boton" value="Insertar" onclick="cargarScript()">
```